# Is there a Dart interface to google actions?

Tags: dart, actions-on-google

I want to reuse some of my business logic and firestore data access, which is written in Dart.  Is there a Dart interface?

Comment: Since Google Actions are server-based, what are you using with Dart to run it on a server?